# Does ROLLBACK TRANSACTION imply a commit if not rolled-back

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

My `SQL-Server` learning curve has been back-to-front and after several yrs I'm battling to use `TRANSACTION` code effectively.

If `COMMIT TRANSACTION` is not explicitly stated then at the point of `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` if no errors have occurred in preceding code will the transaction then be committed? The question is in connection with a structure like the following:

```
USE MyDataBase;
GO
     BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        --complex query X here  
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; PRINT N'Rolled back the transaction.';
GO
```

...I thought `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` was used in a situation where you do not want changes to be made to a db if an error has occured in the *preceding* script - in the above this would be `X`. If i wanted to explicitly state `COMMIT TRANSACTION` in the above then where should it be located?

To confuse myself even more I've got the following - why is it rolling back twice? Is an error occuring to create the `ROLLBACK`?

```
USE WHAnalysis;
GO
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        IF @@TRANCOUNT = 1
            SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
            --do a complex query here

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; PRINT N'Rolled back the transaction.';
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The transaction will remain open and uncommitted until it is committed, which will probably eventually cause blocking on your database.

If transactions are nested, rollback will rollback to the beginning of the outer transaction, not the inner transaction - See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx

I would consider a structure something like

```
 begin try
      begin tran
      -- do query
      commit tran
 end try
 begin catch
      if @@trancount>0 
      begin
          rollback
      end
      -- handle error here
 end catch
```

Comment: to test is there a simple script I can replace `-- do query` with so that an error is created?

Comment: Is this a general `T-SQL` design pattern that you use a lot?

Comment: if they are nested _but named_ then I assume the rollback can be more exact i.e. not necessarily rolledback to the outer transaction